# How to display adsense ads to search engine visitors and social media visitors only?

Tags: javascript, preg-match, adsense, referrer

I made below javascript code for display google adsense ads to search engine visitors and social media visitors only. But code not working with ads.

When i placed adsense ads on below code its show me ads when i visit url from referrer site and also when i visit direct url without referrer its showing me ads. I want to display adsense ads only search engine and social media visitos, not both referrer and without referrer, only referrer visitor can see adsense ads.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.match(/google|bing|facebook|twitter/)) {
    var test = '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google_ad_client = "";
                <!-- 336x280 -->
                google_ad_slot = "";
                google_ad_width = 336px;
                google_ad_height = 280px;
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
            ';
    document.write(test);

} else {
    document.write("its not referrer");
}
</script>
```

When i use this below code its working fine but when i placed ads its not working.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.match(/google|bing|facebook|twitter/)) {
    document.write("its a referrer visitor");

} else {
    document.write("its not referrer");
}
</script>
```

Please help me to solve it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already within a javascript-block, you could just execute the code right away, instead of `document.write`-ing new javascript-code. Using the [asynchronous mode](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en) of adsense, you also gain some page-loading improvements.

```
<!-- Google Adsense will place the ad within the ins-block. Display none
     by default, we will change that in javascript -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:none; width:336px;height:280px;"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.referrer.match(/google|bing|facebook|twitter/)) {
        // Show the ins-block
        document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
        // Load adsense-javascript using
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"; // Note: different url due to async
        script.async = true; // Not necessary, but speeds up loading your page
        var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My mistake, google handles async differently. I've modified my answer

Comment: where i set this code: `<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>`

Comment: i added it below </ins>

Comment: One more question. I want to display 3 different adsense ads, how to i do it using your code?

Comment: i can't design it by html css

Comment: According to the documentation you do only need to load the `adsbygoogle.js` once. Add the `ins`-tags three times, and the javascript (somewhere) after the last one. Of course `document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')[0].style.display = 'inline-block'; should be done three times (`[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` or just a `for`-loop over all of them)